# How can I disable WiFi when computer is connected to LAN with wire, using GPO?

Tags: wireless-networking, group-policy

Is anyone of you know how to disable, thru a GPO, the Wireless connection as soon as the computer is connected to the LAN with a wire.

By example, a user is at home with his laptop, connected to his home wifi connection. He leaves and comes to the office but the Wifi is still enabled. He plugs the ethernet cable in the computer and then, both wifi and wire connection are enable.

I would like to apply a GPO that does this.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this became possible using GPO from Windows 8 onwards:

http://windowsitpro.com/windows-client/block-computer-connecting-non-domain-network

The policy is `"Prohibit connection to non-domain networks when connected to domain authenticated network"` under `Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Network\Windows Connection Manager`

This policy will disable home wireless network interfaces as soon as a domain network is detected.  One does have to be careful though.  The policy isn't very smart and it's possible to lose wireless if using it in combination loopback adapters or adapters that are installed by software such as VMWare.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible to do *exclusively* with Group Policy. You will need to consider one of the other 3rd party solutions to accomplish what you want. (Those, however could be controlled through GP if you like?).

[Here is a supporting TechNet thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/007da9d4-c029-4751-97bc-dd55b798cfa1/disable-wifi-connection-with-gpo-when-network-cable-is-plugged?forum=winserverGP).

Answer (score -1):

.. or you do it the easy way and configure network metrics. Make a GPO to set ethernet metrics to some number, like 50, then set wireless metrics to 100 (or whatever number that is higher than ethernet) and, voila, if an ethernet connection exists, your computer will use it instead of using wireless.

Comment: Do you know where these settings should be applied in GPO?

Comment: This does not solve the security issues regarding having both ethernet and wireless enabled at the same time. I do not see how this answers the question.

Comment: Because metrics set the preference of connectivity. Even if both are enabled, Windows will always use the lower metric for data transfer. It does not explicitly prevent bridging, but it forces certain adapters to be used even if both are available.

Answer (score -2):

**[nvspbind](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/nvspbind)** can change the Network Adapter Binding Priority in Windows. The WLAN can have a higher priority than LAN, but with this utility you can change that, even in a managed environment (since it is a command line utility)!

Example: put the LAN NIC on the top of the binding order for IPv4:

```
nvspbind.exe /++ "Local Area Connection" ms_tcpip
```

Example: put the LAN NIC on the top of the binding order for IPv6:

```
nvspbind.exe /++ "Local Area Connection" ms_tcpip6
```